# Updates for v3 are paid only?

Tags: craft3, pricing

There was this "one time fee" mantra overall and now I read 
https://craftcms.com/news/dot-all-2017-announcements

They will charge additionally on yearly base?
Does this include any update and security updates as well?

Comment: I would also like to know about security updates.

Also, the line **We’ll also be requiring commercial plugins in the Plugin Store to follow suit** makes me a bit nervous. I really hope this doesn't turn into a Shopify type scenario.

Comment: That line about plugins means that *commercial* (as in, not free) plugins will be required to use the same pricing model as Craft itself, i.e. a yearly renewal fee which is some percentage of the initial licensing fee, in order to continue to receive updates for said plugin. Plugin authors are free to set their actual prices, though (and the plugin store will have free plugins too, and there'll be other ways to install plugins than via the store)

Comment: As for the security patches, I'm pretty sure that if you opt out of renewing your license, you won't be able to install _any_ updates, including security updates. I'll try to get the official word on it, though.

Answer (score 4):

Ever since Craft 1 launched in 2013, purchasing a Craft license (Client or Pro editions) has included free updates – even major releases, which means that your current Craft 2 site will be eligible for a free upgrade to Craft 3 once it launches in April 2018.

With the release of Craft 3, this will change: in order for your site to stay updated, you'll have to renew your Client or Pro license yearly, for a reduced fee ($39/year for Client edition, $59/year for Pro). If you opt out of renewing after the first year, you won't receive any further updates, but your license will still be valid and your site will still work.

*Note that the yearly fee does not apply to any existing licenses, which will continue to receive free updates indefinitely*.

Source: https://craftcms.com/news/dot-all-2017-announcements

Comment: In other words … pay or die. Lucky me, I have no Craft installation yet :-) And will never have with this

Comment: That's too bad, @suntrop. From P&T's point of view, maintaining software over time (not to mention supporting a large – and growing – install base) requires resources. As far as I've seen, almost everybody in the Craft community appreciates this and the news about the pricing model change hasn't been controversial. Also, not to make assumptions, but I don't believe $39/$59 _per year_ would sink anybody's budget – unless you're a non-profit, in which case you can get in touch w/ P&T (as mentioned on their [pricing page](https://craftcms.com/pricing)) and they might be able to help you out.

Comment: Note – the above is the only comment I'm going to make to your comment; further discussion on this topic (or any topic, I guess) is probably better had on [the official Slack](https://craftcms.com/community) and not on SE :)